# Android textview width not same

Tags: java, android, textview, margin

I am doing the chat system. So I need to do the UI for showing the message and sent time.
Please see the below images first. The red color is the text view width and blue color is sent time text view width. Now I set the sent time is right of the text view.
I would like to set the sent time text view have a margin. But you can see the text view width is not same. So I am not hard code the margin. So anybody can give me some useful suggestion to me. Thanks a lots.

Comment: i recomend to use contrant layout with guide so you can set textView width with screen percentage

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.60"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
    android:background="@color/red_color"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/_151sdp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:minWidth="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDateTime"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvMessage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvMessage"
    android:textColor="@color/chat_mag_date_time"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But this is not my expectation. I updated the first image. You can see the arrow that is the date time position I want. The date time text view should be different if the message length is too long. I want it is just had a left margin according the longest text in the message

Comment: if the message is only one line, the date time will be overlap the message

Answer (score 0):

For using a **component** in another you can use somethings like : `CardView`,`FrameLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`.

`ConstraintLayout` like this :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/msg_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="151dp"
        android:minWidth="30dp"
        android:text="fdsfdsfd
dsadas
asd
asd
as"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvMessage"
        android:text="1234"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But this is not my expectation. I updated the first image. You can see the arrow that is the date time position I want. The date time text view should be different if the message length is too long. I want it is just had a left margin according the longest text in the message

Comment: if the message is only one line, the date time will be overlap the message

Comment: First of all test it , then add comment @WongManlok

Comment: hi @milad salimi, I just added the margin and please see the result here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/njJBW.png

Comment: the last message is overlap the date time text

Comment: This is not my code , please test MY code! @WongManlok

Comment: hi sorry, just miss some attributes. please see the image again. But this is not my expectation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbJHv.png

Comment: What is your exception exactly??

Comment: can you see my question's first image? I draw the arrow and the arrow is the exactly position of the date time I want. If the message is only 1 line, just give the spacing between menage and the date time. If the message is more than 2 lines, the date time will be move left

Comment: My problem is message text view width is not different. I cannot hardcode to set the left margin. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8i91.png

Answer (score 0):

Add following alignments to the TextView "tvDateTime"

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvMessage"
android:layout_alignRight="@id/tvMessage"
```

and remove the extra alignment instructions, so your TextView code will become:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDateTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="12:45"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/tvMessage"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"/>
```